# Xcode iPhone Date Formatting issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I can't for the life of me figure out why my code wont format the date when it has worked for me before so I figured I would post the code up and see if someone else could spot the issue..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell
int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

cell.textLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];


NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];

NSDate *dateTmp;
dateTmp = [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex]objectForKey: @"date"];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateTmp];
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12.0];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = Light_BACKGROUND;

[dateFormat release];

return cell;
```

}

I have used nslogs to see what information the code is actually making happen and it would seem that it has no problem getting the date from the mutable array but when I try to apply the stringFromDate for the detail text it just returns null so nothing is being placed leaving the detail text blank.

I attempted to set a string so I could check the log and this was the turn out.

```
[1984:207] all done!
[1984:207] stories array has 10 items
[1984:207] DateTmp = Wed, 16 Feb 2011 01:37:16 +0000
[1984:207] DateLine = (null)
[1984:207] DateTmp = Tue, 15 Feb 2011 23:05:31 +0000
[1984:207] DateLine = (null)
[1984:207] DateTmp = Tue, 15 Feb 2011 04:31:36 +0000
[1984:207] DateLine = (null)
[1984:207] DateTmp = Tue, 15 Feb 2011 02:16:01 +0000
[1984:207] DateLine = (null)
[1984:207] DateTmp = Sun, 13 Feb 2011 04:07:42 +0000
[1984:207] DateLine = (null)
[1984:207] DateTmp = Sun, 13 Feb 2011 02:15:41 +0000
[1984:207] DateLine = (null)
[1984:207] DateTmp = Sun, 13 Feb 2011 00:21:42 +0000
[1984:207] DateLine = (null)
[1984:207] DateTmp = Sat, 12 Feb 2011 22:50:27 +0000
[1984:207] DateLine = (null)
[1984:207] DateTmp = Sat, 12 Feb 2011 21:07:27 +0000
[1984:207] DateLine = (null)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you include your NSLog  statements?

Comment: The DateTmp and Dateline information is what I was getting with nslog. Dateline was a nsstring that I made a log for to see if the date was being assigned to the string. For example when running the code I would see the date as it is contained in my array being assigned to a DateTmp. The next step was supposed to be applying the date format to the DateTmp and returning the string for display in a detail textlabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around that will be do, I wasn't able to find the reason I couldn't format the information my only guess left is that is has something to do with how the date is being stored when parsing the information from the twitter feed. Thanks to everyone who assisted me with the issue all of your solutions were good this just seemed to be a weird situation.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems like you're creating the date right, but not retaining what you created. That is probably why you can NSLog the date value during creation. After the creation of the cell the string you made is out of scope, so you get (null). Try setting the cell text label like:

```
 [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[dateFormat stringFromDate:dateTmp]];
```

Comment: went ahead and tried it with the same result as before it is still returning null but since it is a null value in the detail line it just doesn't show the detail text just the title.

Comment: I've used code that looks incredibly similar to what you have as example. The only difference I can find is that I first assign the 

`[dateFormat stringFromDate:dateTmp];` 

to an NSString. i.e. 

`NSString *tempString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateTmp];`

`[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:tempString];`

Might be worth a try?

Comment: yah I thought the same thing and tried it but it has something to do with how the date is not getting formatted most likely how the format is setup.

Comment: Are you using NSDate objects in your stories dictionary? Maybe try using the default formatting for the NSDateFormatter and see if you can see the date without setting up a custom format? Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: No worrys mate thanks for the help I will looks into your suggestion and let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Your `NSDateFormatter`'s `dateFormat` does not match the tmpDate you're showing in your log.

Try this:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZ"]
```

Notice how your date format string is not taking the abbreviated day of the week into account and you have added dashes to the date where there are none.

Here's a page which shows all of the formatting characters used by `NSDateFormatter` (OS X 10.5+ and iOS). [Unicode standard tr35-6](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: I updated the code using the new date formatting and I'm still getting a null value when using the [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateTmp]; I see what you mean about the dashes in the date format I didn't even think about those.

Comment: I have a feeling it could be the date of the month that's tripping it up. Can you check if a date like May 5th would show '05' or '5' for the date. If it's not zero padded you'll want just one 'd' in your format string.

Comment: I checked if changing the format of the setDateformat made a difference and from what I could see its still returning a null value instead of doing a date format.. Im not sure if this helps but the goal is an rss reader detail line that contains the date. Currently it pulls the pubdate from the twitter feed and thats what the first date I have is and I just need it formatted to not have +0000 at the end of it.